# Send Shift/Alt/Ctrl in SendInput

Tags: c#, input, keyboard, key

I'm writing a controller program, which simulates keystrokes to any active application. I found the `SendInput` method like this(I only care for keyboard, so irrelevant definitions omitted):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct INPUT
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Int32 type;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public KEYBDINPUT ki;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public MOUSEINPUT mi;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct KEYBDINPUT
{
    public Int16 wVk;
    public Int16 wScan;
    public Int32 dwFlags;
    public Int32 time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern UInt32 SendInput(UInt32 nInputs, ref INPUT pInputs, int cbSize);
```

I know the `wVk` and `wScan` can be assigned by a `System.Windows.Forms.Keys` enumation value. I also looked at the values, and found `Shift=65536, Control=131072, Alt=262144`(the value of all keys is 1-254). I also know those three values should be in `wScan`(corresponding 1,2,4) and they are modifier state flags. But three questions:

1. For example, I want to send a left Ctrl key to the active application, must I pass both `wVk==LControlKey` and `wScan==Control` right? What will happen if I only pass the first and not the second? And should I pass `wVk==LControlKey; wScan==Control; dwFlags==0`(key down dwFlags), and `wVk==LControlKey; wScan==0; dwFlags==2`(key up dwFlags)?
2. in `Keys` enumation there exist `LControlKey, RControlKey, ControlKey`, what's the third one mean?
3. in `Keys` enumation there exist Control keys and Shift keys, but why not Alt keys? So isn't it possible to send an Alt keystroke by `SendInput` method?

Comment: [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

Comment: You should be using Keys.ShiftKey, Keys.ControlKey and Keys.Menu instead.  The scan code means something completely different, just leave it at 0 for now.

Comment: Yup I just found the name of alt is like `LMenu` that's why I didn't found AltKey...Do you mean just send them is ok, no need to plus the state(Alt, Shift, Ctrl) to vScan?

Comment: Looking for an answer of 3rd Question.